# Why this array_filter method not calling this function?

Tags: php, callback, array-filter

```
private static function returnSameElementIfNotEmpty($item) {
    if (empty($item)) {
        return false;
    }
    else{
        return true;
    }
}


public static function clean($array) {
    return array_filter($array, 'returnSameElementIfNotEmpty');
}
```

When I try running this with a sample array I get:

**Warning: array_filter() expects parameter 2 to be a valid callback, function 'returnSameElementIfNotEmpty' not found or invalid function name in C:\Framework\ArrayMethods.php on line 27**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
return array_filter($array, array(__CLASS__, 'returnSameElementIfNotEmpty'));
```

The error occures because you don't call the class method. But just a function with that name. In the above example I use **CLASS** as the class type to access the static function `returnSameElementIfNotEmpty`.

Comment: I tried like: return array_filter($array, __CLASS__.'::returnSameElementIfNotEmpty'); and it worked, but why is it so?

Comment: See my answer, I've added a small part.

Comment: I tried with self::returnSameElementIfNotEmpty() , that did not help either?

Answer (score 1):

Excellent, in the documentation not mentioned.

array(**CLASS**, 'returnSameElementIfNotEmpty') solves warning

More elegant:

```
$ArrModEmpty = array_filter($array, function($Arr){
                return (empty($Arr));
            });
```